# Overlaying classes with m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

The Maven Eclipse plugnin, now called m2e has a nice feature in it which "dynamically" overlays files. For example,  supposed you have two web projects:
1.  Core project
2.  Application project

You can configure it very easily so that the core project is overlaid into the Application project
(see: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html).  This means if you change a html file in the Core project, as soon as you hit saved it is overlaid and visibile in the Application project! Great.

However, suppose you add a new class in the Core project and you have a dependency to this class in the Application project.

Eclipse will not build the Application project because it cannot see the new class in the Core Project on the classpath.  Ouch!  To get around this, I add the target/classes of the Core Project to my Application's project's classpath.  Not nice.

I am wondering is there a better solution.  Note:I have the dependency marked with scope "compile" but it makes no difference. Similarly, I have also tried selecting project / maven / update project configuration - also no difference.

What I would really like is for m2e is to understand yeah this is a compile dependency so pick up the dependencies at compile time.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have(had) a similar setup and our solution to this problem was to have a common (parent) project for all web projects. Both your web projects would then depend on this shared project.